Sum of dependent Bernoulli random variables
I tried solving this problem.
Let $X_1,X_2, \dots$
be independent and identically distributed variables with $X_i∼\text{Ber}(\frac{1}{2})$
for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. Define $Y_i=\max\{X_i,X_{i+1}\}$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}.$
Let $Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i.$

Calculate the mean and variance of $Z_n$.

Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(Z_n=n/2)=0$.

Prove that the sequence of independent variables ($Z_n/n$)
converges in probability to $3/4$
as $n\to\infty$.


I did solve 1 and 3, the mean and the variance, the mean is $3n/4$
and the variance is $5n/16-1/8$.
I have a problem with the second question.
I do know that $Y_i$ is $\text{Ber}(3/4)$, but I can't deduce that $Z_n$ distribution is $\text{bin}(n,p)$ because the $Y_i$ are dependent.
I tried using the law of total probability on $X_1$, and so on the next $X_i$, but I just couldn't find any pattern.
I also tried Chebyshev's inequality, but it doesn't work as well.
Any help with this question?

P,ease don't use pictures - they cannot come up in searches, and screen readers have trouble with them.

The first thing that comes to my mind would be to use the fact that $Y_i$ and $Y_{i+2}$ are independent.

What is $p$ in the distribution of $Z_n$?

First of all, note $\mathbb{P}(Z_n=n/2)=0$ if $n$ is odd. If $n=2m$, then
$Z_n=U_m+V_m$ where
$$
U_m=Y_1+Y_3+\dots+Y_{2m-1},\quad V_m=Y_2+Y_4+\dots+Y_{2m}
$$
Now $U_m$ and $V_m$ are both Binomial$(m,3/4)$ as their ingredients are independent (but of course $U_m$ and $V_m$ are dependent).
Form the large deviation estimates, we know that for some $c>0$ for all large $m$
$$
\mathbb{P}(|U_m-3m/4|>m/8)\le \exp(-cm)
$$
with the same bound for $V_m$. Let
$$
A_n:=\{|U_m-3m/4|>m/8\}\cup\{|V_m-3m/4|>m/8\}.
$$
On $A_n^c$ we have
$$
|U_m+V_m-3n/4|\le m/8+m/8=n/8 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ Z_n\in[5n/8,7n/8]\not\ni n/2.
$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{P}(Z_n=n/2)\le \mathbb{P}(A_n)\le 2 \exp(-cn/2)\to 0.$$

$A_n$ doesn't have any $n$ in its definition?

thank you, i used your idea of splitting it to Vm and Um and then using the law of total probability, with Stirling's approximation

@RohitPandey, recall that $m=n/2$.

A partial answer that provides a start
Note that $Y_i$ are Bernoulli with probability $\frac 3 4$ of being $1$ and $\frac 1 4$ of being $0$.
So, $E(Y_i) = \frac 3 4$
And they are also dependent. The dependence doesn't matter when calculating the expected value.
So,
$$E(Z_n) = E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i\right) = \frac{3n}{4}$$
For the second part, its trivially true when $n$ is odd.
